# List all ALSA devices

Tags: linux, java, alsa, pulse-audio

I'm using PulseAudio on my system, and I followed the instructions for adding a [monitor device](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/PulseAudio/Examples#ALSA_Monitor_source) as per the PulseAudio wiki. The monitor device itself works and registers/functions properly in apps like Audacity, but I'm not able to get the device to show itself through any of the command line tools. `aplay -L` returns roughly the same list as Audacity, but is conveniently missing the monitor device.

My end goal is to parse the output in a Java app and eventually pass it to FFmpeg. I'm able to tell the device exists through the Java audio APIs as 2 generic "Capture source ports" show up, but it doesn't provide a name for the device, and the goal is for it to be user-selectable in a somewhat friendly manner.

Are there any ways to get the monitor device to show up in either a command line app or through a Java API / library?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this quesiton related to Alsa or Pulse ? As is this is entirely confusing these are totally separate technologies.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the `pacmd list-sources` or `pactl list` commands to show PulseAudio devices. To show only names you can grep on it's output. This is an example from [PulseAudio FAQ](http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/PulseAudio/FAQ)

`$ LANG=C pactl list | grep -A2 'Source #' | grep 'Name: ' | cut -d" " -f2`

With additional grep on ".monitor" you can get only monitor devices.

Comment: Note: PulseAudio devices are *not* always the same as ALSA devices!

Answer (score 6):

So in short, it looks like the problem is up at the alsa level and not at the pulseaudio level? If you want to see the alsa devices try.

```
aplay -l
```

(but aplay -L which you've already mentioned is similar).

pulseaudio sits on top of alsa. So looking at pactl brings in another layer of software... see here troubleshooters.com/linux/sound/sound_troubleshooting.htm. If alsa can't see the sound device then certainly pulseaudio won't?

Answer (score 5):

It's brutally simple:

This shows you the sinks/output ports:

```
aplay -L
```

Since a 'monitor' is a source/input port, you'll want this:

```
arecord -L
```

Update: aplay and arecord are in the 'alsa-utils' package.
To install:

```
sudo apt install alsa-utils
```

Comment: `aplay: not found`

Comment: Install the alsa-utils package, see post (now updated).

Comment: Sorry my comment was more like, I don't have a package manager on the device I want to list them on. And in the Linux world it's surprisingly hard to find pre-compiled binaries

Comment: @Cherona Eh....that's exactly what packages contain: binaries. You can just download packages and unzip them to get at the binaries. 
I don't even know what you mean with "pre-compiled". Packages are built, not compiled.